# Error when constructing Tensorflow Model: FailedPreconditionError

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to construct a model as practice to distinguish between sliced and regular oranges based on a folder of images. Everything goes fine up until I run the command to train the model. The code / error is below.

```
!pip install -q tf-hub-nightly==0.8.0.dev201911110007
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.data_util.image_dataloader import ImageClassifierDataLoader
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.task import image_classifier
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.task.model_spec import efficientnet_b0_spec
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.task.model_spec import ImageModelSpec

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os
oranges = os.path.abspath('/content/sample_data/oranges')

data = ImageClassifierDataLoader.from_folder(oranges)

//THIS LINE IS PRODUCING THE ERROR
model = image_classifier.create(data)
```

[image: Here is the error it produces]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by saving a copy of the notebook to my drive and re opening it. the .ipynb files are checkpoints used by the notebook when you manually save, which is what the error message was referring to. I'm assuming something went wrong with that specific session of the notebook. Regardless, saving a new version on my drive and reopening / running the code shows this issue is solved now.